# Disable weak TLS cipher suites on Azure Service bus

Tags: security, ssl, azureservicebus, tls1.2, rc4-cipher

I had set `minimumTlsVersion` to `1.2` in azure service bus configuration. After Penetration or endpoint scanning on `yournamespace.servicebus.windows.net`. Service still supporting `TLS 1.0` `TLS 1.1`.
and also weak cipher suits are enabled for `TLS 1.2`.

My azure functions use the `.net6.0` target framework and I have applied security protocol at the application startup.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

**How do I disable weak cipher suites for service bus and block any service bus requests that comes from `TLS 1.0` , `TLS 1.1` , `TLS 1.2` ?**

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/transport-layer-security-audit-minimum-version#use-azure-policy-to-enforce-the-minimum-tls-version

Answer (score 0):

About TLS versions, this seems to be a limitation on the Azure Service Bus' current way of setting minimum TLS version.

I understand that the underlying limitation is that service bus instances are shared across many Azure Users, and so while they have a setting in place that can **effectively** prevent one namespace (that is to say, your particular bus) from using some TLS version, it does not mean another namespace on the same service bus would not support it.
In the end, they have to accept (upfront) many versions, and only after, once the actual namespace is resolved, do they enforce this namespace's version.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/transport-layer-security-enforce-minimum-version

> Here're a few important points to consider:
>
> - A network trace would show the successful establishment of a TCP connection and successful TLS negotiation, before a 401 is returned if the TLS version used is less than the minimum TLS version configured.
> - Penetration or endpoint scanning on `yournamespace.servicebus.windows.net` will indicate the support for TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2, as the service continues to support all these protocols. The minimum TLS version, enforced at the namespace level, indicates what the lowest TLS version the namespace will support.

So network checking tools report TLS 1.0 and 1.1 as being supported when Microsoft says they would eventually fail, only later than what the tools suggest.

The being said, I do not have an answer about setting the cipher suites.